# Linq - Set a limit to a group while doing a request

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, windows-8

I'm trying to find an efficient way to set a limit to each of my group in a linq request in C# (7 items by group for example). I don't want to create another group with the extra of one group I just want to pass to another category.

For the moment I'm doing this to fill my groupedList :

```
    public IEnumerable<object> ListByCategory
    {
        get
        {
            var query = from item in listArticles.listArticles 
                        orderby item.categorie
                        group item by item.categorie into g
                        select g;

            return query;
        }
    }
```

I tried to go through this groupedList afterward and remove all the extra element in each category but it is not elegant at all.

Thank you in advance

---

Here is the Xaml part :

```
 <local:MyGridView  x:Name="PicturesGridView" SelectionMode="None"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs1}}" IsItemClickEnabled="True"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomTileItem}" ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" >
        <local:MyGridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
 <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </local:MyGridView.ItemsPanel>
        <local:MyGridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button  Click="Button_Click_1" Content="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Black" Background="White" FontSize="30" Margin="0,0,0,-10" ></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
 <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemWidth="75" ItemHeight="150" Orientation="Vertical"   Margin="0,0,80,0" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </local:MyGridView.GroupStyle>
    </local:MyGridView>
```

Here are the ressources :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomTileItem">
        <Grid >
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <Image Source="{Binding imageUrl}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="30" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding chapo}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>


    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvs1"
                      IsSourceGrouped="True" />
```

and I'm doing the binding like this :

```
            IEnumerable<object> myObject = App.api.ListByCategory;
            this.cvs1.Source = App.api.ListByCategory;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your request correctly, you can just use `Take`:

```
return from item in listArticles.listArticles 
       orderby item.categorie
       group item by item.categorie into g
       select g.Take(7);
```

(Obviously that can be a variable...)

Note that this will lose the fact that it's a grouping, so you'll no longer be able to take the key from each group. If that's a problem, you can select to a new data structure easily enough. For example:

```
return from item in listArticles.listArticles 
       orderby item.categorie
       group item by item.categorie into g
       select new { g.Key, Values = g.Take(7) };
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that and effectively I loose the key for each group and I need it because it feeds  a group style template of a gridView.

Comment: @AstironNaviir: It would have helped if you'd said that to start with. Editing...

Comment: Thank you, it's close but now the number of items for each key is 0 (but in when I expand the list of Values for each key i can see 7 articles...). So my template doesn't see any items and just display the keys...

Comment: @AstironNaviir: Well if the values are there but you're not seeing them, that suggests you haven't got your binding right. Unfortunately you've hardly given us *any* context here (like exactly how you're using the values...) which makes it hard to help you further.

Comment: I'll try to be clearer : before I had inside my IEnumrable<Object> a list of : {System.Linq.Lookup<string,App9.Article>.Grouping}  and now I have { Key = "à la une", Values = {System.Linq.Enumerable.TakeIterator<App9.Article>} }

Comment: @AstironNaviir: Yes, I'd expect that - but you still haven't said what you're doing with it. You could add a call to `ToList()` after `Take` to materialize the query... It's unclear whether that will help or not...

Comment: No I have the same result with ToList() apart that now I have the correct number of items for each category.

Comment: @AstironNaviir: Have you changed the binding as I suggested? You need to tell the XAML to use the `Values` property...

Comment: I know it's been a while. However what you are looking for is ItemsPath="Values" in your XAML source to look at the values.